# Bind variables in a mysql_query statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Example mysql_query:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT `col1`, `col2` FROM `table` WHERE
`col1`='$escapedvariable' ");
```

I know the above is not good in practice.

Better query using prepare and execute

```
$pSt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col1=:col1);

$pSt->execute(array(':col1'=>$escapedvariable);

$status=$pSt->errorCode();
```

**Question: Can I use `mysql_query` with bound variables for added security?**

Comment: NOTE for future readers: The second code snippet (using `prepare`) is for `PDO`. Hence `:col1` as a bound parameter. If instead you are using `mysqli` then use `?` for bound parameters. mysqli parameters are not named - they are determined by their order in the sql.

Answer (score 4):

No, you have to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)-functions or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Vote for put PDO to the first place ;-P

Comment: second vote for PDO => ttp://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/