# How to bind parameters in mysql query?

Tags: php

I have search for bind parameters. But it just getting me confused. I'm really a beginner in php and mysql.

here is code:

```
$query ="UPDATE table_user_skills SET rating='" . $_POST["rating"] . "' where rating_id='".$_POST['id']."'";

$result = $conn->query($query);
```

I wonder if how can i apply the bind parameters method in this sample query. Thanks for you response.

Thanks for all the responses. My code works

**update.php**

```
$sql = "UPDATE table_user_skills SET rating=? WHERE rating_id=?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param('sd', $myrate, $myrateid);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->errno) {
  echo "Error" . $stmt->error;
}
else print 'Your rate is accepted.';

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: You dont have any parameters to bind!?!??!! - RT?M [MYSQLI Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Have you had a look at prepared statements at all? try convert this to the prepared statement then come back and we will fix the little issues left over.

Comment: Is this using the `mysqli_` or `PDO` extension?

Comment: Like this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: [**mysqli** -> Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) && [**pdo** -> Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). There are a bunch of examples in each...

Comment: Do you mean you want us to convert this query to use Bound Parameter?

Comment: @RiggsFolly.. yes.. can you do that? thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly im using mysqli

Comment: yes i will do that.. sorry im new here in stackoverflow..  thanks for that advice :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind variables in a mysql\_query statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836821/bind-variables-in-a-mysql-query-statement)

Answer (score 2):

When you write the query, leave the values (*the `$_POST` variables*) out of the SQL code and in their place use a placeholder. Depending on which interface you're using in PHP to talk to your MySQL database (there's [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) and [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)), you can use named or unnamed place holders in their stead.

### Here's an example using PDO

```
$query = "UPDATE table_user_skills SET rating= :ratings where rating_id= :id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($_POST);
```

What we've done here is send the SQL code to MySQL (*using the [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/pdo.prepare) method*) to get back a [PDOStatement](http://php.net/pdostatement) object (*denoted by `$stmt` in the above example*). We can then send the *data* (*your `$_POST` variables*) to MySQL down a separate path using [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/pdostatement.execute). Notice how the placeholders in the SQL query are named as you expect your `$_POST` variables. So this way the SQL **code** can never be confused with **data** and there is no chance of [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com).

Please see the manuals for more detailed information on using [prepared statements](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: The ops said that they are [using mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129675/how-to-bind-parameters-in-mysql-query#comment63690803_38129675) xD (just in case you want to update your answer)

Comment: @FirstOne we can let him off, he did this before OP said mysqli :P

Comment: thank for this.. how should i pass the value from $_post to the :rating in the query?

Comment: @SeulgiBear, please, there are a bunch of tutorials out there. Can you take some time to study them and come back with a more specific problem?

Comment: @SeulgiBear http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php the examples are good enough to see what is going on and how.

Comment: @FirstOne im doing that right now.. i posted a question here in case my codes doesn't work :)

Comment: @SeulgiBear fyi you don't need to _reserve_ a question slot in the future. Do your work, get your errors then post. By now this is probably on page 2 of the php questions and get less attention.