# issue while set value in mysql table column in shell script

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, shell, ubuntu

--- code line where issue came

```
mysql -u root -p --execute="UPDATE mysql.tSub_SubJob SET Error_Description = '$errorMarkDown' WHERE sub_job_name='$line'"
```

--- Data Type 
$errorMarkDown LongText

-- value of $errorMarkDown which is insert into table

```
2019/10/22 05:07:17 - Stored_orders - ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05 15.35.36 by buildguy) : (stderr) rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/Data_Files/hiveworx_shell_files/AWS_Stored_orders.csv.gz': No such file or directory
```

-- Error

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '': No such file or directory' WHERE
>   sub_job_name='AWS_Shelves_Details'' at line 1

Comment: LongText Data Type in which i want to update .. Value is too large . i don't know what issue come while set value.

Comment: Retest it with an empty `$errorMarkDown` variable. Probably you have to escape the content of  `$errorMarkDown`. Btw. It's always a bad idea to use string pasting with SQL

Comment: @jeb thanks for your response .                 Still same error came.. 
when i simple string set in **$errorMarkDown** variable. then it goes run fine . 
but when i want to set text which mentioned in my question then this error come  . 
i think issue of too large string and special characters present in string..

Comment: You could test that with a string with the same length of current variable but all  characters set to ex. `A`. Or event better, you could use bind parameters [How to bind parameters in mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38129836/463115)

Comment: @jeb yes i did it . it's working fine but when i set montioned above string then give error.

Comment: Solved .. It's all because of some special character's . when i cleaned this text then inserted successfully in mysql table.    Thanks @jeb