# INNER JOIN tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table **books** with rows: bookID, bookTitle, bookDecription and authorID, and another one **authors** with rows: authorID, firstName , lastName.

In my website, when i click on one author i have to display all the books that are connected to the author, i have tried something like:

```
$query = "SELECT books.bookID, 
                 books.bookTitle,
                 books.bookDescription, 
                 authors.firstName, 
                 authors.lastName
            FROM books 
           INNER JOIN authors ON books.authorID = authors.authorID;";
```

but it's showing the author firstName and lastName only.

Here is my php code:

```
$books3 = readAuthorFromAuthors($connection);

foreach($books3 as $key => $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='bookTitle'>".$row['bookTitle'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['bookDescription']. "</td>";
    echo "<td class='bookTitle'>".$row['firstName']. " " .$row['lastName'].  "</td>";
```

And here is my function :

```
function readAuthorFromAuthors($connection) {

$query = "SELECT books.bookID, books.bookTitle, books.bookISBN, books.bookFormat, books.bookLanguage, books.bookPublisher, authors.firstName, authors.lastName FROM books INNER JOIN authors ON books.authorID = authors.authorID;";

$result = mysqli_query( $connection, $query );

$books3 = [];

if($result ){
// result_n! check results
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $books3[] = $row;
    }
   return $books3;
}
else{
    echo "Error " . mysqli_error($connection);
} 
}
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: there's no problem with the SQL, try to inspect the php code. Btw, using aliases for the tables may make easier to read the query.

Comment: My teacher told me that i have to use INNER JOIN, thats why i have been trying it like this, but i just cant figure in out. When i click on the author, it just displays his firstName and lastName

Comment: Hi! The phrase "it's not working" doesn't actually describe a problem - what did you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Remember that we can't see any code you don't give us, so try to create a [mcve] - show us the input data and the expected output, but spend some time narrowing the problem down first. You've added the PHP tag, but only shown us SQL; are you sure it's the SQL failing, or is the PHP code relevant? You may find that trying to describe the problem more clearly helps you solve it yourself.

Comment: Then you just need to add a WHERE clause with a condition containing a bind variable for the author ID to the end of the query string such as  `....  WHERE authors.authorID=?;"`, and of course set that variable's value within the code.

Comment: I have edited the question, im new here so i didnt know what to write hahah, you can see the whole code now.

Comment: I don't know php, but I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129675/how-to-bind-parameters-in-mysql-query) might help for the bind variable usage.